# Nothing is appearing in the iOS simulator when I tried to allow users to create their own uicollectionviewcell

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

My code is building perfectly and I am trying to use the simulator but nothing is appearing but a blank white screen. I am trying to allow the user to create their own uicollectionviewcell with a title and an image. I have a ChatRoom View controller that has the initial entry point it also has a navigation controller segue connected as  the root view controller. I also have a subclass ChatCell for the UicollectionViewcell. How can I fix this ? Here is my github of the project: https://github.com/fboch25/CollectionView2

//Subclass

```
class ChatCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var chatLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var chatImage: UIImageView!

}
```

// Original View Controller

```
class ChatRoom: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {



@IBOutlet weak var collectionView2: UICollectionView!



var secondClass : ChatCell?

struct Object {
    var image: UIImage!
    var title: String!
}

// Properties
var object: Object?
var objects: [Object] = []
var picker: UIImagePickerController!


// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker?.allowsEditing = false
    picker?.delegate = self
    picker?.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    // NavigationBar Characteristics
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.black
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    // self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Logout", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleLogout))
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.green
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "+", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(didSelectCreateButton))
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.green

}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell
    let object = objects[indexPath.row]

    secondClass?.chatLabel.text = object.title ?? ""
    secondClass?.chatImage.image = object.image ?? UIImage()


    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return objects.count

}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    switch info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
    case let .some(image):
        object?.image = image
    default:
        break
    }

    picker.dismiss(animated: true) {
        self.showCellTitleAlert()
    }
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {

    object = nil

    dismiss(animated: true) {
        self.collectionView2!.reloadData()
    }
}

// Alerts

func showCellTitleAlert() {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Cell Title", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)

    alert.addTextField { $0.placeholder = "Title" }
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { _ in
        self.object = nil
    })
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default) { _ in
        self.object?.title = (alert.textFields?.first.flatMap { $0.text })!
        self.object.flatMap { self.objects.append($0) }
        self.collectionView2?.reloadData()
    })

    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

// Create new Cell
////////?//////////////
@IBAction func didSelectCreateButton() {

    object = Object()

    present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}

Comment: I suggest you add a dummy background color to your collectionView and see if that changes. if it doesn't then something deeper is wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your viewDidLoad add these two lines

```
collectionView2.delegate = self
collectionView2.dataSource = self
```

For your particular project I would make two changes.  One change the button in the top right corners text to white so you can see it.  Two change this method and you will start seeing your cells.  Cannot believe I did not notice in the code above..

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ChatCell
    let object = objects[indexPath.row]

    cell.chatLabel.text = object.title ?? ""
    cell.chatImage.image = object.image ?? UIImage()
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, when I put it in the viewdidload it says UICollectionview has no 'datasource'

Comment: It still does nothing, im not sure whats going on

Comment: Can I zip my project?

Comment: @KimRiegel you can upload your project on github and share its link in your question....

Comment: @Honey yes I can

Comment: sure.  I will take a look

Comment: The project seems to be empty

Comment: @KimRiegel i can look at it tomorrow

Comment: Give me just and I will take a look

Comment: @agibson007 Ok Thank you for your help! Let me know of anything you come up with.

Comment: check it now.  you are good to go with the answer above.  Please do me a solid and mark this one correct after you test and can confirm